# Contar linhas e colunas nulas de uma matriz

Tags: c, matriz, array

Galera, me ajudem na seguinte questão:

***Escreva um programa completo na linguagem C que declare uma matriz quadrada de tamanho
5x5. Em seguida, seu programa deve preencher essa matriz aleatoriamente com 0s e 1s (a matriz
gerada deve ser diferente a cada execução do programa). Por fim, seu programa deve informar
quantas linhas e colunas nulas a matriz possui. Segue um exemplo de saída do programa. Nesse
programa o usuário não fornece dados de entrada.
Matriz gerada:***

```
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0

A matriz possui 1 linha e 2 colunas nulas!
```

O codigo que fiz nao consegue ler as linhas e colunas nulas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    int matriz[5][5];
    int linha, coluna, x, count_linha, count_coluna;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Matriz Gerada: \n");

    for(linha=0; linha<5; linha++){
        printf("\n");
            for(coluna=0; coluna<5; coluna++){
                x= rand() %2 + 0;
                printf("%3d",x);
                matriz[linha][coluna];
                if(linha==0){
                    count_linha++;
                }
                if(coluna==0){
                    count_coluna++;
                }
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("A matriz tem %d linhas nulas, e %d colunas nulas",count_linha, count_coluna);
}
```

Comment: Sugiro separar seu programa em pedaços (funções, se já souber o que é isso).

Comment: Só o que seu programa faz certo é gerar números aleatórios.

Comment: A sugestão do Pablo é boa, mas não acho que o Stack Overflow seja o lugar pra pedir que te ensinem a fazer o seu trabalho, e sim para tirar dúvidas específicas sobre como resolver problemas nele.

Answer (score 2):

Como indicado num comentario do Pablo Almeida, tenta separar o codigo em pedacos diferenciados (em funcoes), cada um a fazer uma coisa.

Por exemplo, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    int matriz[5][5];
    int count_linha, count_coluna;

    // Primeiro: inicializar gerador de numeros aleatorios
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Segundo: preencher matriz
    for (int linha = 0; linha < 5; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 5; coluna++) {
            // int x = rand() % 2; // substitui para preencher com mais zeros
            int x = rand() % 4 - 2; if (x < 0) x = 0;
            matriz[linha][coluna] = x;
        }
    }

    // Terceiro: imprimir matriz
    printf("Matriz Gerada:\n");
    for (int linha = 0; linha < 5; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 5; coluna++) {
            printf("%3d", matriz[linha][coluna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Quarto: contar linhas nulas
    count_linha = 0;
    for (int linha = 0; linha < 5; linha++) {
        int zeros = 0;
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 5; coluna++) {
            if (matriz[linha][coluna] == 0) zeros++;
        }
        if (zeros == 5) count_linha++;
    }

    // Quinto: contar colunas nulas
    count_coluna = 0;
    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 5; coluna++) {
        int zeros = 0;
        for (int linha = 0; linha < 5; linha++) {
            if (matriz[linha][coluna] == 0) zeros++;
        }
        if (zeros == 5) count_coluna++;
    }

    // Sexto: imprimir resultado final
    printf("A matriz tem %d linhas nulas e %d colunas nulas\n",
           count_linha, count_coluna);
    return 0;
}
```

Podes ver [a funcionar no ideone](https://ideone.com/Q4Lqrw).

Comment: @JoaoSaraiva (proponente de edicao): usar a definicao das variaveis dentro do ciclo `for` serve para fazer notar melhor que as partes em questao sao isoladas. O C99 tem quase 20 anos! Se ainda ha compiladores que nao o aceitam, para esses compiladores tambem seria necessario alterar os comentarios para `/* ,,, */` em vez de `// ...`